# Trying to add/remove classes from a div in the paretn document outside an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Using jQuery, I'm trying to affect a div that lives outside an iframe in the parent document on click of a button within the iframe (*the sources are on the same server*). I've tried all sorts of syntax variations to get this done, but am having no success. What is the proper syntax for this? Any help is greatly appreciated, as I'm pretty new to this.

```
$(".show-add").click(function() { // I'm a button inside an iframe
    event.preventDefault();

    // I'm outside the iframe in the parent document
    window.parent.document.$("." + $(this).data('section') + "-next-step").addClass("hidden");
    window.parent.document.$("." + $(this).data('section') + "-save-experience").addClass("show");
});
```

Comment: can you try `$($(this).data('section') + "-next-step", window.parent.document).addClass('hidden');`?

Comment: It should be `parent.$`, not `parent.document.$`; jQuery is defined as a global variable - a property of `window` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that `$(this).data('section')` returns valid data and that this data could be found in the parent window meaning it allows access to an existing element which is valid, why not try something more simple like an element with a known ID just to make sure it is accessible.

Second try to access the element directly from `window.parent.` as follows:

```
$(".show-add").click(function() { // I'm a button inside an iframe
    event.preventDefault();

    // I'm outside the iframe in the parent document
    window.parent.$("." + $(this).data('section') + "-next-step").addClass("hidden");
   window.parent.$("." + $(this).data('section') + "-save-experience").addClass("show");
});
```